# Visual C# Error: The type or namespace name 'Compression' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'

Tags: c#, build, compiler-errors, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to compile a tile map editor so I can use it to work on a game, but I am getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Compression' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'" when I try to build in Visual C#. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried google but I found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't have a reference to `System.dll`, or you're using a version of .NET before version 2.0.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0. How would I add a reference to System.dll?

Comment: @user1150769: Right-click "References" in the Solution Explorer pane and click Add Reference, then look for System.dll.